# Java: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError Failed to call native method in .cpp file using JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

as mentioned in title my java program is unable to invoke or call the native method in .cpp file where the library .dll gets loaded successfully in program.
but while running it throws an exception `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`.
I had correctly set a library path to project.

here is my cpp file:

```
#include "jni.h"
#include "Demojni.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "c"{
   JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL _Java_demojni_Demojni_printm(JNIEnv *env, jobject   object){
      cout<<"call from c++";
      return 1;
   }
}

int main(){
   return 1; 
}
```

and here is .java file:

```
package demojni;

public class Jni1{
   private native int printm();
   static{
      try{
         System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
         System.loadLibrary("libCppJNILibrary_1");
         System.out.println("loaded");
      }
      catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("can't load\n"+e.getMessage());
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] arg){
      Jni1 api=new Jni1();
      int a=api.printm();
   }
}
```

Comment: Why is there an underscore at the beginning of `_Java_demojni_Demojni_printm`? Also, the class name you've specified in your native code is `Demojni`, but in the java code it's `Jni1`.

Comment: I got my mistake thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to match method name and package name.

Take a look here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html

Section: "Resolving Native Method Names"

In fact, the easies way to have everything set up properly is to use javah.

Take a look at simple Hello world sample here:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/

Answer (score 0):

You changed the name of the class from `DemoJNI1` to `Jni1` without regenerating the .h file and/or without adjusting the name of the JNI method in the .c file.

Comment: You should consider upvoting any answers you find useful, and accepting the one you find most useful.